# Генерация HMAC в Angular

Tags: angular

С помощью какого пакета и как стоит генерировать `HMAC` в `Angular 7`?
Пробовал с помощью `angular-crypto-js`, но он даже не установился. 
Буду благодарен за помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: почему вы привязываетесь к `Angular 7`? используйте [SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto), к тому же - `angular-crypto-js` предназначен для первой версии Angular

Comment: @overthesanity, потому что нужно выполнить на Анугляре =)

Comment: чем hmac будет отличаться если генерировать ключ на проекте где есть react/vue/ember? кардинально что-то поменяется? =))

Comment: @overthesanity, ничем =)
Но вот нужно именно на Ангуляре, чтобы он принимал слово, к примеру, "Первый", ключ длиной 128 бит и выдавал хэш)

Comment: я вам еще раз говорю - не привязывайтесь к Angular ;))

Comment: @overthesanity, с большой радостью... )